# How to slice matrix with logic sign?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I can apply the following code to an array.

```
from numpy import *
A = eye(4)
A[A[:,1] > 0.5,:]
```

But How can I apply the similar method to a mat?

```
A = mat(eye(4))
A[A[:,1] > 0.5,:]
```

I know the above code is wrong, but what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, when `A` is a `numpy.matrix`, `A[:,1]` returns a *2-d* matrix, and therefore `A[:,1] > 0.5` is also 2-d.  Anything that makes this expression look like the same thing that is created when `A` is an `ndarray` will work.  For example, you can write `A.A[:,1] > 0.5` (the `.A` attribute returns an `ndarray` view of the matrix), or `(A[:,1] > 0.5).A1` (the `A1` attribute returns a flatten `ndarray`).

For example,

```
In [119]: A
Out[119]: 
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [120]: A[(A[:, 1] > 0.5).A1,:]
Out[120]: matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])

In [121]: A[A.A[:, 1] > 0.5,:]
Out[121]: matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Because of quirks like these, I (and many others) recommend avoiding the `numpy.matrix` class.  Most code can be written just as easily by using `ndarray`s throughout.

Comment: Thank you.  Your method works well on selecting row vectors.  But what about selecting column vectors if I don't want to transpose the matrix first and then apply the above method?